# Converting time format in simpleWeather.js

Tags: momentjs

I want to convert the time from the standard 12-hour reading to the 24-hour one in simpleWeather. When I try to do it, it returns the time in the Unix epoch format.

```
$(function sunset(){
  var sunset=
 $.simpleWeather({
  location:'Dalol,Afar',
    woeid:'',
    units:'f',
    success:function(weather){
        var Sunset= moment(weather.sunset, "HH:mm:ss");
     html='Sunset: '+Sunset;


    $('#sunset').html(html);
   }
    });

  });
```

I had contacted the developer on how to do convert it using moment.js, but he didn't say much more than that. How can the code be corrected to display the desired format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first parse and then format the `weather.sunset` with the right formatting:

```
var sunset = moment(weather.sunset, ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm");
```

`simpleWeather.js` returns the sunset as "5:31 pm" so the corresponding moment format to parse this date is `h:mm A`, where the A captures the pm/am. To format it in the 24-hour notation, `format("HH:mm")` will do the job.